# Regex for removing trailing zeros

Tags: .net, regex

I am looking for a regular expression (.NET) to remove trailing zeros:

```
11645766.560000001000   ->  11645766.560000001
10190045.740000000000   ->  10190045.74
1455720.820000000100    ->  1455720.8200000001
```

etc...

---

I am using regex, over String.Trim(), because the numbers are in one string, actual example:

```
!BEGIN !>>C85.18 POS_LEVEL.T129{11645766.560000001000} = POS_LEVEL.T129 {10190045.740000000000} + WORK_LEVEL.T129{1455720.820000000100} END;
```

need to convert to:

```
!BEGIN !>>C85.18 POS_LEVEL.T129{11645766.560000001} = POS_LEVEL.T129{10190045.74} + WORK_LEVEL.T129{1455720.8200000001} END;
```

Comment: Deleted my response since the question has changed significantly from the original.

Comment: A solution should be found on SO for the problem of the "Barbapapa" questions (i.e. questions that are completely different a few hours after the original one was posted)

Answer (score 17):

If the numbers are embedded in a random string, regexes are the way to go:

Replace **`(?<=\.\d+?)0+(?=\D|$)`** with an empty string

That will trim trailing zeros if they appear after the period in a decimal number (it will always leave a single zero). It also accounts for numbers that appear at the very end.

And since you've added the .NET tag in the meantime, here's the code:

```
string replaced = Regex.Replace(
                         inputString,
                         @"(?<=\.\d+?)0+(?=\D|$)",
                         String.Empty);
```

Comment: I tested all of the sample numbers with the Replace feature at http://regexhero.net/ and your regex works perfectly.

Comment: Oh well, I guess whoever downvoted doesn't like the idea that a regex could be the best solution to solve this problem

Comment: Where does it fail? I've tested it and I can't see anything wrong with it. Can you be more specific?

Comment: i'm under the impression that you can't use the + or * characters in the lookbehinds. also when trying your regex at gskinner.com/regexr it doesn't work. do some regex's have different standards?
fyi i'm not downvoter.

Comment: They certainly work in .NET regular expressions. I don't know about other implementations.

Comment: You can use + or * in lookbehinds with the .NET regular expression engine.  gskinner.com/regexr doesn't use the .NET engine though.  But regexhero.net does.

Comment: I suspect part of the reason for the downvotes is that we couldn't see the first backslash in the lookbehind; you should ALWAYS use backticks or indented code blocks to format regexes.

Answer (score 7):

In .Net you can do the following

```
var newStr = Regex.Replace(input, "0+$",String.Empty);
```

Comment: +1 - The original question vs. the edited one are completely different questions.  You didn't deserve the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
([0]+)\b
```

then delete $1

Comment: +1 - The original question vs. the editted one are completely different questions.  You didn't deserve the down vote.

Comment: That's one of the problems with SO.

Comment: in my limited experience the '.' is considered a word boundary character making this implementation delete a zero before the point.

Comment: Victor's right. Instead of \b, I would suggest (?![.\d]) - "not followed by a dot or a digit". At least, until the OP changes the requirements again. ;)

Comment: But you don't need to capture the zeroes and explicitly delete them. Just replace the matched text with an empty string, like activa did.

Answer (score -1):

One caveat on the above RegEx AND Trim()... if your input does NOT have a decimal point, you could end up with wrong numbers. E.g., ("1000").TrimEnd('0') = 1.

This workaround will fix that issue:

```
string Trimmed = (Untrimmed.IndexOf('.')>=0) ? Untrimmed.TrimEnd('0') : Untrimmed;
```

Of course, the use of a "." for decimals is culture-specific--some cultures use commas. If you're trying to built in culture-awareness, you need to use System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberDecimalSeparator instead of a literal '.' character.

**Edit:** Based on your edited question above, RegEx is the right answer. Something like:

```
Trimmed = RegEx.Replace(Untrimmed, "(\d\.\d*[1-9])0+([^\d]|$)", "$1$2");
```

(The [1-9] above is my lazy way to avoid \d being greedy and capturing the 0's, there's likely a more straightforward way to do it.)

Answer (score -1):

The following will match zeros that follow a decimal point and any number of decimals, and that do not precede a decimal point or digit.

```
(?<=\.\d*)(0+)(?=[^.\d])
```

Comment: Because it doesn't address the question asked.

The questioner asked for something that did this:
11645766.560000001000   ->  11645766.560000001
10190045.740000000000   ->  10190045.74
1455720.820000000100    ->  1455720.8200000001  

According to The Regulator, yours does this:
11645766.560000001000   ->  .560000001000  
10190045.740000000000   ->  .740000000000   
1455720.820000000100    ->