# Regular expression to remove trailing zeros of a decimal number

Tags: regex

I need to build a regular expression to match the trailing zeros to the right of the decimal point.

With this regex `/,0+$/` I can match all zeros to the right of the comma, including the coma, for example, `123,000` and `123,00`, but the zero in this decimal number `123,450` is not matched.

If I use this regex `/0+$/`, I can match the zero in `123,450` but it matches also the zero in this number `120`. How can I match the trailing zeros only after the comma?

Comment: What is your regex tool or flavor?

Comment: I am using https://regex101.com/ to test.

Comment: Asking more specifically, what programming language are you using your regex in?

Comment: Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve? Match said zeros or remove them? And if latter, what should happen to 123,00? Should it become `123`, `123,`, or `123,0`?

Comment: See also this one: [Regex for removing trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1105653/735926).

Comment: Why is regex the tool of choice here? You can parse the number in your language of choice and output it in a different format if needed? It might also better handle culture if the decimal seperator is different, because some cultures swap the decimal and thousand seperator, making matching with regex a pain.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it doesn't matter what language, that is why I didn't specify it. I am using regex101 tool. If the regex works there, it will work in JavaScript, Java, C#, and so on.

Comment: @markalex I need to remove all zeros to the left of the comma. For example, 123,000 should become 123. 123,050 should become 123,05. 123,450 should become 123,45. 123,456 should become the same, 123,456. And final example, 120 should become 120.

Comment: @JimWolff I can do that. It is clear I can create a function to remove zeros to the right but it could be not so efficient when there are a lot of data to process.

Comment: @jstuardo, do you understand that "remove all zeros to the left(presumably right) of the comma" and `123,00 -> 123` (no comma!) and `123,050 -> 123,05` (only one of zeroes is removed) are very much different things?

Comment: Also, this examples must be part of the question, not comments.

Comment: "it doesn't matter what language" "If the regex works there [regex101], it will work in JavaScript, Java, C#, and so on" - __NO__. Different languages support different syntax. For example, answer provided by bird, will not work in java or python. Selection of language in regex101 is there for a good reason, and for the same reason, you are expected to specify what language or tool is expected to be used with your regex.

Comment: @markalex From my experience, when I debug a regular expression (using, for example, regex101.com), I can use it in every language. Maybe your experience is different, but solution given by anubhava worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @jstuardo, this not matter of "experience", but of facts: different features, like lookbehind of variable length patterns, lookarounds in general, matched sequence resets and others have different level of support in different engines. If you want as an answer regex, that will be supported by most languages, it would be better to specify that in question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match using this regex:

```bash
(?:(,[0-9]*[1-9])|,)0+$
```

and replace with:

```
$1
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bD9OCV/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(,[0-9]*[1-9])`: Match a comma followed by 0+ instances of a digit and a digit `1-9`. Capture this value in group #1 (to be used in replacement back-reference `$1`)
  - `|`: OR
  - `,`: Match a comma
- `)`: End non-capture group
- `0+`: Match 1+ of zeroes
- `$`: End

Comment: I'd prefer `\d` instead of `[0-9]` but results are the same, maybe this is more understandable, idk.

Comment: Or just `(,([0-9]*[1-9])?)0*` if in larger text or just `(,(.*[^0])?)0*` if the whole input is the number.

Comment: It worked! however, if number is integer, for example, `123,000`, there is no group. So if there is no group, replacement should be just `''`. If there is group, replacement is $1.

Comment: @jstuardo: When first capture group is empty then `$1` will also be empty.

Answer (score 2):

If an infinite quantifier in a lookbehind assertion is supported you can either match a comma, or assert that to the left from the current position is a comma followed by 1 or more digits.

Then match 1 or more zeroes to the end of the string, and replace with an empty string.

```
(?:,|(?<=,\d+))0+$
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternatives

  - `,` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `(?<=,\d+)` Positive lookbehind, assert `,` and 1+ digits to the left
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `0+` Match 1+ times a zero
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PJlQzP/1).

Comment: Good solution if variable length lookbehind is supported like modern JS or C#

Answer (score -2):

> *"... How can I match the trailing zeros only after the comma?"*

I presume you actually mean *trailing* zeros, and not a singular zero.

The following infers that the value *is* a decimal value.
So, I guess the infraction here is that it would additionally match the *0* in *120*.

```
(?<!,)0+$
```

The negative look-behind will assert that the value before the initial repeating *0* is not a comma.

So, it will preserve a singular *0* after the comma.

For example,

```
123,000
123,00
123,450
```

Would become the following, if the match is removed.

```
123,0
123,0
123,45
```

If you did want to remove a singular *0*, you could append the pattern.

```
(?<!,)0+$|,0+
```

```
123
123
123,45
```